# Adjusting space between columns in Axlsx generated bar graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I am using the Ruby on Rails Axlsx gem (https://github.com/randym/axlsx) to create an Excel export with a column graph, using the following code:

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new(author: @current_user.username, workbook: Axlsx::Workbook.new)
wb = p.workbook
sheet = wb.add_worksheet(name: 'My worksheet')
sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::Bar3DChart, start_at: 'A2', end_at: 'K28') do |chart|
  chart.barDir = :col
  chart.show_legend = false
  chart.valAxis.gridlines = true
  chart.catAxis.gridlines = false
  chart.gapWidth = '50%'
  chart.add_series(data: [1,2,3], labels: ['This', 'That', 'Other'], title: 'My chart')
end
```

Looking at [the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/Bar3DChart#gap_width%3D-instance_method), it seems I can use `gapWidth=` to adjust the space between bars. Using `chart.gapWidth = '50%'` doesn't throw an error, but when I open the generated file up in Excel, it tells me the file is corrupted. If I remove that line, everything works fine.

Can someone tell me how I can adjust the space between bars in my generated graph?

Comment: very weird. In documentation I found this: "validation regex for gap amount percent    /0*(([0-9])|([1-9][0-9])|([1-4][0-9][0-9])|500)%/", and after that I went to "RegEx String Generator", to reverse this.. and the results are this: "500%, 0000029%..." ... I tried all of them, but also get file corrupted. =(

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be because the value given is inserted verbatim into the gapWidth node, though the value is a percentage it shouldn't include the '%' sign in the emitted value.

So for your example it will produce the node `<c:gapWidth val="50%"/>` instead of `<c:gapWidth val="50"/>`

Best fix I think is just to remove the requirement for the % symbol in the validator.

You're welcome to use my cloned repo for now which has that fix.
https://github.com/kstuart/axlsx